# react-native PushNotificationIos compile error

Tags: ios, objective-c, react-native, react-native-push-notification

TL;DR How to use UNNotificationRequest with react-native?

Trying to implement push notification handling in react-native. In the react-native documentation it says that I should add the following to my AppDelegate.m:

```
// Required to register for notifications
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterUserNotificationSettings:(UIUserNotificationSettings *)notificationSettings
{
  [RCTPushNotificationManager didRegisterUserNotificationSettings:notificationSettings];
}
// Required for the register event.
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken
{
  [RCTPushNotificationManager didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:deviceToken];
}
// Required for the notification event. You must call the completion handler after handling the remote notification.
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
                                                      fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler
{
  [RCTPushNotificationManager didReceiveRemoteNotification:userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:completionHandler];
}
// Required for the registrationError event.
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError *)error
{
  [RCTPushNotificationManager didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:error];
}
// Required for the localNotification event.
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification
{
  [RCTPushNotificationManager didReceiveLocalNotification:notification];
}
```

The problem is that the local notification method gives me a build error:

```
'UILocalNotification' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 10.0 - Use UserNotifications Framework's UNNotificationRequest
```

So that's easy to fix, I just need to use UNNotificationRequest, right? My question is, how do I import it?
The doc page looks like this:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unnotificationrequest

They assume that I know how to import it. Which I do not. How do I find out how to do this?

PS: No swift please. objc only. react-native uses objc.

Comment: did you find any solution?

Comment: Yeah, I rm -rf'ed my whole project and recloned it. Worked like a charm. These deprecation warnings aren't what's causing the build to fail